# Trouble in getting selected item text in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

```
@Html.DropDownList("city",(SelectListItem)ViewBag.city,new { @class = "form-control", @onchange="fun1()"})


 $(document).ready(function fun1() {

        alert("Selected item value is " + $("#city").val() + " and Selected item 
          text is " + $("#city option:selected").text());

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

write your function `function fun1()` outside document.ready. It will work.